# Postgresql wildcards to search functions

Tags: search, wildcard, postgresql

Is there a way in Postgresql to call \ef or \df on a function or table name with wildcards.
An example of the way I think it would work is \ef fn_%some%get%function%

This way I could find functions even if I only know part of the table or function name.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use wildcards, this is explained in detail in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS